# Setting Dialog Size Programmatically

Tags: android, dialog, size, height, width

In my program I create a dialog with the code below. Ideally I would like to scale the dialog by entering width and height parameter programmatically. Can anyone show me how to do this?

```
dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
popUpLayout = Globals.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_layout, null);
dialog.setContentView(popUpLayout);
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here is the code that ended up working:

```
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(275, 350);
```

Comment: incase you want to match params, this might help. dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: @PhillipKigenyi your code did not work for me on SDK 30

Comment: @MiguelSilva Well I haven't investigated the changes in SDK 30, best guess is that there is an open api to do just the same implementation. Sorry for the inconvenience caused

Comment: @PhillipKigenyi no sorry necessary! ...i ended you defined the dimensions on the dialog's layout XML file